# Installing a Nvidia FX 5600 AGP to replace SiS onboard graphics

Tags: 11.10, drivers, upgrade, nvidia

My first question so please bear with me.

I have a Compaq SR1417cl with an ASUS built K8SLA motherboard, AMD Sempron 1.8Ghz CPU and a SiS 760 onboard graphics chip. It also has 2GB of DDR ram. I have Onieric 11.10 installed on it's own 120G drive and Windows XP installed on a separate 40G drive.

Everything works OK...In Ubuntu I get nothing but 2D. I am using the Gnome classic desktop although Unity 2D works as well. I have not even tried installing compiz settings mgr. I can watch streaming video but occasionally if I try to do too much everything freezes..I just hit the power button and restart the hard way..It works? I guess since there is no such thing as a Linux SiS driver, I must be using a vesa driver.

There are no entries in "install additional drivers. So, now I want something that let's me run compiz and use unity 3D..I have bought an Nvidia FX 5600 256MB AGP 8x card. The mother board will support it. My question is, when I install this card is there anything I should prepare first? Should I remove the vesa driver? Or just install the card and go to additional drivers to see if there is a Nvidia driver? Your help is appreciated. I am not real good yet with terminal commands but I follow instructions well. I will be happy to be rid of the SiS...Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case just insert the video card, boot up in Ubuntu and go to the **Additional Drivers**. After installing the Nvidia proprietary driver, Ubuntu will take care of changing the vesa you are using for the Nvidia one. That is done automatically.

So basically, install the video, card, install the proprietary drivers, reboot, done.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to remove vesa driver. Insert Nvidia card, start ubuntu. Ubuntu will automatically detect your graphics card. Because ubuntu 11.10 has KMS support. Ubuntu will detect your nvidia card as VGA[default display]. To install the driver[to get 3D support] for your nvidia card you can use jocky[additional driver] from ubuntu or download nvidia driver from here http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually install the 173 driver for your card, by downloading it from the nvidia website.